# Creating and supplying mock objects as arguments

Tags: unit-testing, interface, mocking

I'm trying to restructure my project so that I'm developing to an interface to eventually
be able to create mock objects for testing and I'm having trouble 
implementing/understanding some of the concepts. I have an `IProducts` interface which
is implemented by `Products`. But obviously I'd like to be able to create a mock Products 
object.

How do I get it to depend on the interface and not the implementation?

```
public void AddNewProduct()
        {
            IDatabase db = new Database();
            IProducts products = new Products();
            products.addProductsToCache();
        }
```

i.e. How would I specify this code to use the `MockDatabase` object instead.

Comment: Edited question + code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd pass the product to the method:

```
public class YourProductContainerClass
{
    private readonly IDatabase _database;
    private readonly IProducts _products;

    public YourProductContainerClass(
        IDatabase database,
        IProducts products)
    {
        _database = database;
        _products = products;
    }

    public void AddNewProduct(IProduct product)
    {
        products.Add(product);
    }
}
```

Just my 2 cents on it. I never create an `interface` just "because I might write a test at a later point in time". I write my unit test, and therefore I need an interface.

> If I am not writing a unit test, then I also don't create an
>   interface.

**Why not?** Because it can very well be the case that the need for a unit test will never get enough priority for all kinds of reasons. Then you have the maintenance cost of updating your code + interfaces while it does not really add something in your design (other than increasing the amount of LoC).

So, imho: get used to writing tests before function. If for whatever reason you don't see the need for unit tests, also consider if writing an interface for the class makes sense.

PS: Tools like `Resharper` make it very easy to extract an interface at a later point in time and refactor the legacy to your interface. It's also a charm with TDD, it takes a lot of pain away.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an Inventory class that you want to test. Inventory has a dependency on IProducts. So it shouldn't care which implementation of Iproducts it uses. The only thig that matters is that it must be an instance of IProducts. In production, the instanes of IProducts will be instances of Products. In tests, it will be instances of a mock Iproducts.

If you introduce an interface (IProducts), but Inventory still depends on the concrete Products class, then your interface is useless. It should only depend o the interface, and not on the implementation.

Comment: I think that's what my question is. How do I get it to depend on the interface and not the implementation?

Comment: Your question basically boild down to: what is dependency injection. See http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Motivation for an explanation (and Google, which has plenty of links about it). Your class should not create instances of its dependencies. It should receive them in the constructor of through setter methods.